# Munin "Disk usage" is too high?

Tags: debian-lenny, disk-space-utilization

I've recently installed munin on my VMware client server and saw that the Disk usage shows about 80-90%. Everything else (cpu load, ram, etc.) seems to be running fine. I have only two virtual hosts on my server with 1000 users/day in total, so I don't think that's too much.

[Here is](http://img64.imageshack.us/img64/4843/diskusage.png) the graph for the disk usage.

Server info: Debian Lenny, CPU 510Mhz, RAM 512MB

Is it bad? What could possibly cause this?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/var` directory is used for various things which can cause this. For example a log file, mail queue or database. You can use the command `du` to see which directory is taking most of the disk space and take appropriate actions.

```
du -h --max-depth=2 /var
```

Comment: Oh, stupid me. I thought the disk usage was some kind of disk load indicator :-)

Comment: In my limited experience munin itself uses more disk space than anything else.

Answer (score -1):

could configure 'munin' to contact 'nagios' monitoring solution if anything goes wrong with 'munin' as http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/HowToContactNagios

this way you can judge the effect of munin over the situation